# Automate LaTeX compilation in Bash by getting changed tex files from Git?

Tags: bash, git, latex, pdflatex

I want to get the changed Tex files from Git to Bash variable so that I can automate the compilation process of changed tex files.

*Example*

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Article/main.tex
```

where I would like to run a script with command `pdflatex Article/main.tex` after getting the path from git.

### **How can I get the changed Tex files from Git to Bash variable in order to compile them with pdflatex?**

*Suggestions*

1. latexdiff [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/using-latexdiff-with-git)
2. latexmk [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40759/2956)
3. make commented by deadObed
4. `git diff --name-only` in the comment by Lea Gris

Comment: I believe that this is what `make` is for... or are there requirements `make` cannot meet?

Comment: @dedObed I don't know. It is notoriously difficult to use basic make for this, according to this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40759/2956), hence it looks there is something called latexmk more [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40738/how-to-properly-make-a-latex-project). I don't know yet which information to trust. Have you used basic make for this?

Comment: `git diff --name-only`

Comment: @hhh I do have good experience compiling conference papers (~4 pages; ~5 figures compiled as standalone) with vanilla `make`.

Comment: @dedObed `make` assumes that if a rule is executed once, it is done.  However, when running a flavor of `latex` it is not uncommon to have to run it multiple times to fix unresolved references. And if you have a bibliography you need to run `bibtex` or `biber` in between. And things like `makeindex`. It's not really a good fit for `make`. Hence tools like `latexmk`.

Comment: You would also have to watch for changes in *anything* that is included in one way or another. In short, you would need to run `*latex` with the `-recorder` option and parse the resulting `.fls` file.

Comment: @RolandSmith Aye to most of your points. However for a fairly static setup where I know that I want `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and `pdflatex` for my main document, and `pdflatex` for standalone figures, it's sufficient (and I found it easier to set up back on the first document, now it's just copypasting the Makefile around :-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous options for this. I thank Lea Gris for working on the solutions here.

### **Alternatives**

*1. For a single changed Tex file, this will do it*

```
pdflatex `git diff --name-only | grep *.tex`
```

*2. For many directories of changed Tex files, they must have different names, where the compiled PDF files will emerge in the current directory.*

```
git diff --name-only '*.tex' | xargs -l1 pdflatex
```

*3. For the same-named, changed Tex files, Lea commented (haven't yet got it working, trying to understand it, I option explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282403/xargs-i-option))*

```
git diff --name-only '*.tex' | xargs -l1 -I{} sh -c 'cd "${1%/*}"; pdflatex "$1"' _ {}
```

### **Solid solutions**

*4. Try Latexmk, a special version of make, doing all recompiling and rebuilt things just for LaTeX. Instead of bash, I find Python far easier to use over different systems such that*

```
import os  
Articles   =["A","B","C"]

for article in Articles:
    #Compiling
    os.system("latexmk -pdf -auxdir=tmp "+article)
```

*where we use latexmk for compiling. Then the below shows how you can utilise the script with a Makefile.*

*Makefile*

```
all:
     python runAboveScript.py

clean:
     os.system("rm *.snm")
     os.system("rm *.nav")
     #Add here everything you want to clean.
```

**Further information**

1. Makefile for a latex project [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318569/makefile-for-a-latex-report/318595#318595)
2. Latexmk more [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361379/latexmk-and-makefile-with-multiple-sources)

Comment: `git diff --name-only '*.tex' | xargs -l1 pdflatex`

Comment: @LéaGris Yes, it works the moment you haven't yet committed the file so not necessarily getting the last update to the compiled file if forgetting to compile. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: I meant no grep needed.

Comment: @LéaGris when you do that it will compile everything to the current directory, a problem if all tex files of the same name in other folders, is there a way to make them compile to their own directories?

Comment: `git diff --name-only '*.tex' | xargs -l1 -I{} sh -c 'cd "${1%/*}"; pdflatex "$1"' _ {}`

Comment: @LéaGris can't get it working with that, trying to understand the command.